# Getting input from text field in one ViewController and using in another class

Tags: ios, swift

A very similar question was asked already, but the solution has not seemed to work for me. I'm sure I'm still doing something wrong. I have a class, `ViewController.swift`, that has a two text field, `usernameTextField` and `passwordTextField`. This page also uses a `prepare()` func in order to segue from this vc once the user has been authenticated. The segue leads to another ViewController, `HomeViewController`.

I have a third ViewController `LocationViewController` that is not a segue from the original `ViewController`, but I would like this VC to access the `usernameTextField` value that was submitted by the user in the beginning. For some reason, once switched to the LocationVC, its `viewController` property is **nil**, thus I cannot access the `userState` property that I really need for the API request.

So far, I have the following in `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var userState = ""
    
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
        
    let users = [
        User(username: "a", password: "1", state: "california"),
        User(username: "b", password: "2", state: "delaware"),
        User(username: "c", password: "3", state: "pennsylvania"),
        User(username: "d", password: "4", state: "new-york"),
        User(username: "e", password: "5", state: "new-jersey"),
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        Authenticate(username: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!)
        assignState(for: usernameTextField.text!)
        let locationVC = LocationViewController()
        locationVC.viewController = self
    }
    
    func assignState(for username: String) {
        for account in users {
            if username == account.username {
                self.userState = account.state
            }
        }
    }

    func Authenticate(username: String, password: String) {
        for user in users {
            if user.username == username && user.password == password {
                return;
            }
        }
        Alert(title: "Invalid Credentials", message: "We could not find an account with that username and password combination. Please try again.")
    }
    
    func Alert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) in alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) } ))
        print("alert dismissed!")
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

And then I have the following in `LocationViewController`:

```
class LocationViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var viewController: ViewController?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getTestingLocations()
    }
            
    func getTestingLocations() {
        let state = self.viewController!.usernameTextField!
        let apiURL: String = "https://covid-19-testing.github.io/locations/\(state)/complete.json"
        guard let cURL = URL(string: apiURL) else { return }
        let request = URLRequest(url: cURL)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let str = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(str)
            }
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Create a variable under LocationViewController.  And pass a value to it from the first view controller.  There are hundreds of similar topics here.  Read them all.

Comment: Or (as ugly as some people regard it), put the data you need your LocatonViewController in a global variable (or static variable in `ViewController`, which is really just a global with a better name space).

Comment: The `locationVC` variable is just thrown away at the end of `prepare` - That view controller instance is never shown.  You need to create an appropriate data model object and pass that object through your view controller hierarchy. From `ViewController` to `HomeViewController` and then to `LocationViewController`

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not sure that there is a 'hierarchy', as this storyboard uses a tab bar controller; any tab can be selected in any order, and there are 4 tabs total, with `LocationViewController` leading to one of them.

Comment: That doesn't matter.  From the tab bar controller you can still get a reference to each of the contained view controllers in order to inject a reference to the model object.

Comment: @ElTomato I am unable to create a global variable within `LocationViewController` that gets assigned a value from the viewController reference. I've tried the following

var viewController: ViewController?
var state = self.viewController!.userState!

but Swift doesn't seem to like the fact that I reference the viewController outside of a method.

Comment: @ChipJarred So I've been trying this, but I don't think Swift likes when I make a global variable in `LocatiomViewController` and try to assign it a value from the `viewController` instance I have. I am only able to do this successfully within a function, which seems to always have viewController as null, as someone has already mentioned is because after `prepare()` gets called, everything defined within the function gets destroyed. Am I missing something?

Comment: If I understand your object relationships correctly, `static` `userState` would should be in `ViewController`.    Then in `LocationViewControler` you refer to `ViewController. userState`.

Comment: Alternatively you can add an explicit initializer to `LocationViewController` and pass in `userState` from `ViewController`'s `prepare()` method.  Or for that matter... you know what?  I'll just add an answer with an example.

Comment: How does `getTestingLocations()` get called?  Is there a `LocationViewController` being awakened from a Storyboard?  If so that's a different instance that then one being created in `prepare()`.  It's not being hooked into a view anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: @DonnellDebnam after a false start from thinking about what was happening the wrong way, I *think* understand what's going on and updated my answer with what I believe to the the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So after squinting at your code for a while longer, I *think* you're segueing to a `LocationViewController`, which means you need something like this:

```swift
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 
    {
        if let locationVC = seque.destination as? LocationViewController
        {
            Authenticate(username: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!)
            assignState(for: usernameTextField.text!)
            locationVC.viewController = self
        }
    }
```

Basically you have to set the `viewController` property in the *existing* `LocationViewController` from the `seque`.

The code you had just created a new one that immediately went out of scope, and even if you had kept a reference to it, it still would not have been the instance attached to the view you're sequeing to.

Comment: So, I don't actually segue to `LocationViewController`, I segue to a completely different view controller within a tab bar controller; `LocationViewController` is just one of the tabs within the tab controller. I don't want the data passed through a segue, because I'm not just going from A -> B, or ViewController -> LocationViewController... there are intermediary steps in between. I need `LocationViewController` to be able to grab the value from `ViewController` at any time.

Comment: In that case, provide an initializer for `LocationViewContoller` to pass in the `ViewController` so you can set it before calling super.init().  Then it will be set when `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: So in your `prepare(...)` method, instead of `let locationVC = LocationViewController()` you will have something like `let locationVC = LocationViewController(viewController: self)`